# No puedo validar un formulario con jquery validate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web, jquery-validate

Estoy intentando validar un formulario con jquery validate, pero siempre que relleno el formulario aparece como que no hay errores. Además si cambio los scripts de js al head en vez de ponerlos al final del body, no me funciona el botón que activa el formulario. EL objetivo es conseguir un formulario que se valide a medida que el usuario introduce los datos. Luego se realizará otra validación en el servidor.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#signup-form").validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        password: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            maxlength: 8
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        surname: {
            required: true
        },
        birthdate: {
            required: true,
            pattern: "/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([1][26]|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/"
        }
    }


});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="popup popup-signup black-background">
    <form id="signup-form" name="signup-form">
        <div class="form">
            <h3>SIGN UP</h3>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="username">Username <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="password">Password <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="name">Name <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="surname">Surname <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Enter surname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="email">Email <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="name@domain.extension">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="email">Birthdate <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" id="birthdate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-37T7leoNS06R80c8Ulq7cdCDU5MNQBwlYoy1TX/WUsLFC2eYNqtKlV0QjH7r8JpG/S0GUMZwebnVFLPd6SU5yg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/scripts.js"></script>
```

En el css tambien probé llamando a la clase .invalid en vez de .error pero tampoco funcionaba.
CSS:

```
    input.error, textarea.error{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

input.valid, textarea.valid{
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery validate se configura a partir del atributo `name` de cada elemento del formulario, no del `id`. Personalmente suelo nombrar los `id` de los formularios como `id_<nombre-del-campo>` para evitar confusiones.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#signup-form").validate({
      rules: {
          username: {
              required: true,
              minlength: 3
          },
          password: {
              required: true,
              number: true,
              maxlength: 8
          },
          email: {
              required: true,
              email: true
          },
          name: {
              required: true
          },
          surname: {
              required: true
          },
          birthdate: {
              required: true,
              pattern: "/^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([1][26]|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/"
          }
      }


  });
});
```

```css
input.error, textarea.error{
    border: 2px solid red;
}

input.valid, textarea.valid{
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="popup popup-signup black-background">
    <form id="signup-form" name="signup-form">
        <div class="form">
            <h3>SIGN UP</h3>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="id_username">Username <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="id_username" placeholder="Enter username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="id_password">Password <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" placeholder="Enter password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="id_name">Name <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="id_name" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="id_surname">Surname <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="id_surname" placeholder="Enter surname">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="id_email">Email <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="id_email" placeholder="name@domain.extension">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label for="id_birthdate">Birthdate <p class="required">*</p></label>
                <input type="text" name="birthdate" id="id_birthdate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-37T7leoNS06R80c8Ulq7cdCDU5MNQBwlYoy1TX/WUsLFC2eYNqtKlV0QjH7r8JpG/S0GUMZwebnVFLPd6SU5yg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Adjunto link a la documentación del parámetro `rules` concretando esa peculiaridad que te comenta el compañero: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules